# How get contact Item related to Email TO, CC, BCC

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

Is there any way to get corresponding Contact item to Sender, Recipients CC and BCC properties ?

I want to avoid searching inside contact folder by email.

I am new with VSTO development, and sorry for bad English ;)
Appreciate your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to avoid searching by email in the Contacts folder - there is nothing linking an incoming  email sender or recipient to a contact in your private Contacts folder.

Comment: email.Recipients.ResolveAll(); and recipent.AddressEntry.GetContact(); is this will work or not ?

Comment: No, AddressEntry.GetContact() parses the address entry object entry id to extract the IPM.Contact item's entry id and open it. But that special OAB entry id is only present on the emails that you compose. Incoming messages have a regular one-off entry id that embeds the name and address only.